# Sending mail with a custom MIME Message using Camel

Tags: java, email, apache-camel, spring-integration

I want to send a multipart MIME message (custom headers, plain text and HTML) using Camel. I can see in the source code that if I send a `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` in the body of a Camel message to the mail component, it send it without creating a new one. But in order to create a new `MimeMessage` you need to have at least a `javax.mail.Session` so you can write `MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session)`. How can I obtain that session in Camel?

If I remember correctly, in Spring Integration the mail outbound channel adapter need a `JavaMailSender` to do its job and you can ask this `JavaMailSender` for a new `MimeMessage` because it have the `Session`. How I do the same thing with Camel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the session.

You can build the `text/html` message as your body, but then specify a header to hold your plaintext body. Check out the `alternativeBodyHeader` option in the docs. In this way, Camel will build your multi-part message for you.